Why is read repair not sufficient in making dynamo-style database linearizable?
I am reading DDIA. It says "possible to make Dynamo-style quorums linearizable at the cost of reduced performance: a reader must perform read repair (see “Read repair and antientropy” on page 178) synchronously, before returning results to the application [23], and a writer must read the latest state of a quorum of nodes before sending its writes."
What benefits are in requiring "a writer must read the latest state of a quorum of nodes before sending its writes?"
Read repair would fix the example in figure 1, and I can't come up with a reason or an example where a writer should perform a bunch of reads before doing the write, especially assuming that it's unconditional.



So what if there is 1 case where "a writer must read ..." is not necessary? The language isn't clear, presumably it means "a writer must read ..." in order for every case it ends up in to work.

"Use text, not images, for text."

ref: DDIA, is Designing Data-Intensive Application, see https://dataintensive.net/

The way I understand it, the author is not saying that the writers need to read the value but that they should check the latest state of the cluster's write quorum (i.e. can the writer see all 'w' nodes) and should hold off writing if it is not met. Otherwise, you can end up reading stale data of a write that was never deemed successful in the first place, even if the subsequent read was a 'read-repair', thereby violating linearizability.
In the quoted example (n=3, w=3, r=2), say the writer was only connected to Replica-1 (and not all 3 of them) and yet initiated a write of x=1, which of course went on to be considered a failure (since replicas 2 and 3 did not get updated). Now if the Reader A and Reader B did the read-repair as per the diagram, using latest-write-wins, all 3 replicas will have x=1. This is incorrect because readers must have gotten x=0 since the earlier write was deemed a failure.
Note that the readers A and B could have begun after we get the response for the write and we would still end up in the same situation. It is also possible that you can end up in this state even if the writer can talk to all 3 replicas but say the write failed on 2 of them due to disk errors. So checking the quorum before write is only a partial requirement.
In summary, any leaderless replication just relying on quorum based consistency is not 100% linearizable.

I think regardless of whether the strict quorum model is enough to be linearizable, the point of checking status before writes still seems useless just because nodes could have failed in between checking the status and making write requests (albeit less likelihood)

@ZackLight Yes, the failure can happen after the checking is done (I mention this in my 3rd paragraph) but if you know beforehand that your next write can corrupt the data in a irreversible way (i.e. there is no rollback mechanism), then it is prudent not to do it.

You have made the conclusion that "any leaderless replication just relying on quorum based consistency is not 100% linearizable" That contradicts with the statement in the book that it's "possible to make Dynamo-style quorums linearizable". Are we perhaps missing critical steps in the implementations that can address your concern of accidentally repairing failed commits?

Breaking up the comment since it is beyond the word limit:
(1/n)
OK, so I think the author is vague the description of 'w' and 'r'. In page 179 which you referenced, he says for 'w' that "every write must be confirmed by w nodes to be considered successful", which is the correct thing, whereas for Fig 9.6 where w=3, he says "The quorum condition is met (w + r > n)", but the write quorum will be met only after the writer gets a success from all 3 replicas.

(2/n)
This has not yet happened by the time readers A and B do the read. Ideally, both these readers should get 0 which is the last known correct value. i.e. reader-A must not do the last-write-wins-read-repair when it encounters a mismatch or return a 1 like the author says, It must instead simply fail the read.

(3/n)
Repairs (whether it is via read-repair or a separate anti-entropy daemon) must consider all 3 node's values before doing the repair. So for n=3 and r=2, maybe if we read from 2 nodes and the values match, it is fine, but if they don't, then either fail the read or do a repair by reading all 3 nodes, ensuring that 2 out of 3 are fine, heal the 3rd one AND THEN serve the actual read to the client.

Yes, my understanding is that a read repair must read from a minimum of n - w + 1 nodes to determine if the latest value comes from a successful write or not. I think the book is just confusing in bringing up read repair right after the example in 9-6, which doesn't show/meet the read repair conditions. The one that does meet the conditions is figure 5-10, when read repair is first introduced.

author here. Sorry that this is not written very clearly. We'll revise this explanation in the upcoming second edition.
The reason a writer must first read from a quorum is because it needs to get the highest timestamp (aka version/tag) of any value that has been written to a quorum of replicas. This is important when there are multiple clients making writes. If client A makes a write, and then client B overwrites the value written by A, it's important that B's write has a higher timestamp since otherwise it won't overwrite correctly. If B doesn't first make a read, it won't know A's timestamp, and therefore could not guarantee that B's timestamp would be higher.
For details, see Section 4 of the following paper:
Nancy Lynch and Alex Shvartsman. Robust Emulation of Shared Memory
Using Dynamic Quorum-Acknowledged Broadcasts. 27th Annual International Symposium on Fault-Tolerant Computing (FTCS), June 1997.
The answer by itisravi is unfortunately not correct. The write of x=1 has not failed, it's just incomplete by the time that Reader A reads it. Holding off writes is not the answer, because you can never know whether the time is now right to go ahead with the write. Moreover, even if a write fails (i.e. it does not manage to get acknowledgements from a quorum within some timeout), clients may or may not read the partially written value; the failure of a write does not guarantee that the write didn't take effect.

Wow, answer from the OG himself  :-). ZackLigh, please feel free to un-accept my answer.
@Martin Kleppman, In the explanation for Fig 9.6, is it correct that the reader A returns the new value 1? i.e. for a reader, does r=2 imply that the 2 values read must be the same for the read to be successful OR is it sufficient that a client just needs to read from 2 replicas and pick the one with the higher version/tag?

I do wonder how the system handles the race condition that both A and B get a higher timestamp after reading T1 from a quorum and then both propose T1 + 1. The paper does sense pretty dense...
"Moreover, even if a write fails (i.e. it does not manage to get acknowledgements from a quorum within some timeout), clients may or may not read the partially written value; the failure of a write does not guarantee that the write didn't take effect" seems to suggest that the system loses linearizability after encountering failures?

@itisravi: Yes, A returns 1. A reader always returns the value with the highest timestamp, even if it was only received from one replica (but if some replicas don't have that value, the client writes it back to those replicas before returning).
Zack: The timestamps are globally unique (e.g. by including a client ID in the timestamp), so two concurrent writes will have different timestamps, but their order is arbitrary. It's still linearizable, even when there are failures; a failed write is just one where the client doesn't know whether it took effect or not.

@MartinKleppmann - "The timestamps are globally unique (e.g. by including a client ID in the timestamp), so two concurrent writes will have different timestamps" - So the conflicts in this case would be resolved by using for example higher client ID in case both clients end up providing clientIdA + T1 + 1 and clientIdB + T1 + 1 for a write after reading T1 from a quorum ?

@MartinKleppmann
Another question I have is that in the text you mention leaderless replication with LWW is not linearizable, so aren't we falling back on the same concept by attaching arbitrary timestamps (although from clients side in this case)
